# Different Bokeh chart behavior between stand-alone and Bokeh server

Tags: python, bokeh

I have some basic code that should produce seven points on a sine wave:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
y = np.sin(x)

plot = figure()
plot.line(x,y)

curdoc().add_root(plot)
```

When I run my bokeh server, I get the following image:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHAl4.jpg)

My Bokeh server produces extremely large numbers on the y-axis.  I do not have this same issue when building a stand-alone chart.

Comment: I should also add that I'm using:Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit) and bokeh version 0.12.4

Comment: I can't reproduce this only my system with either `0.12.4` or with a fresh build off master. I would suggest taking this to GitHub with additional platform details.

Comment: Tried the same code in a different (chrome) browser and it rendered correctly.  Must be an issue with IE - Internet Explorer version 11.0.9600.18537

Comment: Can you file a GH issue? https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues